# What do empty white circles mean in a quantum circuit?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate, shors-algorithm

I'm studying Shor's algorithm.
but I see from the beginning this empty circle.
what this circle means??

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a "negative" control.

In other terms, the gate in your circuit will apply a NOT on the last qubit if and only if the following conditions are both met:

- $\vert x_3\rangle = \vert 0 \rangle$
- the first ancilla qubit is in the state $\vert 1 \rangle$.

A "normal" control (i.e. not an empty circle) would change the first condition to $\vert x_3 \rangle = \vert 1 \rangle$.

Comment: Thank you very much!! you are so kind :) Have a nice day!!